# LinkedIn login - receiving null AccessToken

Tags: android, ios, linkedin-api

I created two apps (iOS + android) with LinkedIn login. I followed all provided docs and tutorials. Everything worked well and I was able to use this login without problems.

However recently I tried to create clones of these app and tried to use the same linkedin app to provide login functionality. Again I followed all docs and tutorials provided, but I was not successful to make it work. LinkedIn started to return me null AccessToken. Specifically the response looks like this:

```
{"expiresOn":0}
```

I then tried to get my apps to previous working state, but was not successful. I am still getting the null AccessToken even in my previously working state.

The problem is that I am not getting any error, the call is successful but the AccessToken is null as mentioned.

I checked my Linkedin developers console. All hashes, bundle ids, suffixes, app ID, ... seem to be correct.